# How to send text input through a submit button to a column in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql, html

I have a table with 6 columns and then one textbox and one submit button.
What I'm looking for is that the information that I'm typing in the textbox is going to be saved in one of the columns (or like pop up in the column that is currently empty).
I have no idea how to proceed at this point, I've been googling a lot but all in vain.

I have done some events in jquery that allows the columns to switch colors when clicking on them. (This is for a single page application (and I'm not using php when it comes to databases etc..).

I would appreciate all help I can get! I'm new to webdevelopment as I have only coded in C#.

```
        <div id="table-columns">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class ="tr-table">
                        <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                        <td class="mytd" style="border-top: groove;"></td>
                    </tr>

        <td>
             <input id="Information" type="text" name="Information"/>
        </td>
         <td>
             <input id="ActivateButtonId" type="submit" value="Activate">
        </td>
```

Comment: that just looks like invalid html. No `<tr>` for last set of `<td>` s?

Comment: So you want to click on a button and change text in the `td` with the `input` value?

Comment: which td do you want to put the value of textfield in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LV74t/)**

Check this,

- This snippet current save the value in the text box, in the first column - `td:first`
- To set the value inside a column- `<td>` you need to use `.text()` and `.val()` to get the textbox value.

---

```
$('#ActivateButtonId').click(function(){
    $('.table tr td:first').text($('input[type="text"]').val());
});
```

Comment: It finally works! I've been figuring that function out for ages! 
The input comes out in the first column. Thank you so much!
Now I have to figure out how to manipulate the code so that the input comes out in the other columns. Sensing which one of them is empty.

Comment: It finally works! I've been figuring that function out for ages! 
The input comes out in the first column. Thank you so much!
Now I have to figure out how to manipulate the code so that the input comes out in the other columns. Sensing which one of them is empty..